# how can I test drag in vue-test-util

Tags: jestjs, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils

I use vue-test-util in my vue3 program

```
  Sortable.create(el, {
        animation: 180,
        delay: 0,
        handle: '.el-table__row',
        draggable: '.el-table__row',
        group: {
          name: 'shared',
        },
        direction: 'vertical',
        onEnd: dragOnEnd,
      });
```

When I drag the table, the `dragonend`event will be triggered in my browser !

but how can I trigger it in my test file ? I want my test to cover this function。